# determining fourier series & coefficients of $ f(x) = e^{z|x|} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I want to determine the fourier coefficients and series of $$ f(x) = e^{z|x|} $$ where $ z\in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0 \} $ on the intervall $ [0, 2\pi ]$.

So let's get started:

$ \hat{f} (n)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{z|x|} e^{-inx} dx $

$ = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{2 \pi}  1e^{zx-inx} dx $

=$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} [[ \frac{1}{z-in} e^{zx-inx} ]_0^{2 \pi} - \int_0^{2\pi} 0 dx ]$ (partial integration)

=$\frac{1}{2 \pi} [ \frac{1}{z-in} ( e^{2\pi z} e^{-2 \pi i z} -1 )]$

I am new to fourieranalysis, so I am not sure if thats on the right way..
also not sure how to proceed or doing it another way

thanks for any help!

Comment: Note that your integration by parts is essentially just finding the indefinite integral $\int e^{a x} dx$. You have a typo in the last line where you need to substitute $x = 2 \pi$. Once you fix that (and you can simplify $e^{-2 \pi i n}$), you have the correct expression for the $n$th Fourier coefficient.

Comment: @Maxim thank you for your comment! yeah, the partial int. was unnecessary ^^ . but I don't get where there is a typo ! I calculated it once again, and I do get the same result.

Comment: You need to evaluate $e^{z x - i n x} \rvert_{x = 2 \pi}$, and you're getting $e^{2 \pi z} e^{-2 \pi i z}$, which isn't right.

Comment: okay, it should be $ \frac{ e^{2 \pi z}}{ e^{2 \pi in}} $ how can i simplify  $ e^{2 \pi i n} $ ? i know that $ e^{n \pi i }= (-1)^n $

Comment: $e^{\pi i n} = (-1)^n$ is a special case of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).